# Xcode 9 - Safe Area Layout Guides Error Comes Back

Tags: ios8, xcode9, safearealayoutguide

I am making a game in SpriteKit for iOS, and I want my app to support iOS 8.0 devices. I changed my deployment target to 8.0, and suddenly I have an error:

```
Main.storyboard:7Ti-J4-z1q: error: Safe Area Layout Guide before iOS 9.0
```

So I Google how to disable them, and I uncheck the "Safe Area Layout Guide" box in all of my storyboards:

[image: This is what the panel looks like in the storyboard editor]

I build again, only to the same error, even though it is unchecked. I tried restarting Xcode, deleting and recreating the storyboards, but nothing seems to work!

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After restarting Xcode, the check box reappears checked, even after unchecking and saving.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after searching through settings, I realized that you also have to uncheck safe area layout guides under your view controller, so now I have unchecked it there and it builds successfully!